# Pdo update not returning false when it should

Tags: php, pdo

I have the following PHP snippet which should return false when the WHERE clause doesn't match. 
***For ex:*** I don't have any **selector value** with **ghddd** in the database so it is supposed that the update shouldn't take place and I should get **Failure** but I keep getting **Success**. Where am I doing wrong?

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['authUser'])) {
        $cookie_contents = $_COOKIE['authUser'];
        //list($selector, $plain_token) = explode(':', $cookie_contents);
        $selector = "ghddd";
        //Empty the values
        $query = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE auth_tokens SET token=:token, expires=:expires WHERE selector = '".$selector."'");
        if($query->execute(array(
            ":token" => "",
            ":expires" => ""
        ))) {
            echo 'Success';
        }
        else {
            echo 'Failure';
        }
        // Delete the authentication cookie
        //setcookie('authUser', "", time() - 1);
    }
```

Comment: Why should your `execute` return `false`? You're probably wanting to check [rowCount](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php), not whether the execute was successful.

Comment: If no rows have been updated that's not mean that your query failed.

Comment: Why are you binding token and expires, but not selector?

Comment: @JonStirling I want to check whether row was updated. For ex: If I have a selector value which doesnt match the any selector value in the db I want it to echo a failure. So what should I do?

Comment: @aynber, I should have done that. Missed it for the moment.

Comment: @Ayan Please read what I linked to in my first comment. That's what you're after.

Comment: @Ayan Is there a problem with the link I gave you, or are you just after somebody to give you the working code...

Comment: @JonStirling, absolutely not. That's not my nature. I have and am learning to code on my own and obviously with help and advice of people like you and others over here. Anyway, yes it does work with the link you gave. Wish I could have given you an upvote if you would have answered it in the answer section. Still, Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want check if your `UPDATE` query has actually updated one or more rows, you can use [PDOStatement::rowCount](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) after the execution of the query.

Answer (score 0):

> A few Observations: 
>   1.) You bound `expires` and `token` but not `selector`. 
>   2.) You may want to remove the colon ( **:** ) in front of the array containing the named-parameters.

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['authUser'])) {
    $cookie_contents = $_COOKIE['authUser'];
    $selector        = "ghddd";

    $query           = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE auth_tokens 
                                      SET token=:token, 
                                      expires=:expires WHERE 
                                      selector=:selector");

    // $query->execute(...) IS EXPECTED TO RETURN A BOOLEAN TRUE OR FALSE.
    if( $query->execute(array(
        "token"     => "",        //<== COLON (:) REMOVED   
        "expires"   => "",        //<== COLON (:) REMOVED  
        "selector"  => $selector  
    ))) {
          echo 'Success';         //<== EXPECTING BOOLEAN 'TRUE' FROM $query->execute
    }
    else {
          echo 'Failure';         //<== EXPECTING BOOLEAN 'FALSE' FROM $query->execute
    }
}
```

Comment: While there is an improvement compared to the original code, this doesn't answer the question that was asked.

Comment: @JonStirling  As it also does not merit your down-vote but it's all good ;-)

Comment: Perhaps I'm odd, but I don't see how answering a question that wasn't asked would merit anything _but_ a downvote?

Comment: @JonStirling   ***Odd Fellows are the best Fellows ---*** Yeah.... perhaps... **:-)** *Thankfully, they are not gods, 'cos the entire planet would be only a wasteland of nothingness if they were  or perhaps they all are ;-)*

Comment: @Poiz. I tried this before but it keeps giving me success even if selector value doesn't match any selector value in my Db.

Comment: @Ayan    Sure, because the update was successful.... The Query executed smoothly. If you want, you could just check  for something like the affected rows. Maybe, that's what you were looking for...

Comment: @Ayan  Check out the Post with `PDOStatement::rowCount `. It is most likely what you were looking for....

Comment: @Poiz, yes it is what I was looking..Thanks :)